# How to build the head tag?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a custom template page and I'd like to add things in the `<head>` tag while having the Wordpress header.

`get_header` will add the `<head>` tag and the actual header in the `<body>` portion.

How can I be more precise to build the page mixing Wordpress elements and my custom elements in both the `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

For example, I'd like to add the `<title>` tag myself because it's dynamic and add some CSS/JS to load.

Note that I am not building a theme or want to edit a theme. I want to reuse the current theme. I am creating a plugin that adds a custom page and I want to reuse the installed theme + do some custom additions in the header only for my custom page.

Comment: Its the same as changing any template part in a theme, you just need to create your own custom header template.

Comment: I want to reuse the current theme, though. I am using a plugin that adds a custom page and I want to reuse the installed theme + do some custom additions.

Comment: We can only answer based on the information you give us - which clearly is not the answer you are looking for. If you have specific requirements, you need to include them in your question so that we can help with an answer that will work for you!

Comment: I did not mention the plugin thing but I did not mention it was part of a theme either. I'll try to clarify the question. Thanks

Comment: There header *is* part of the theme so the assumption is that is what you want... just like you don't need to say your plugin is in the plugins folder - its assumed unless you say otherwise :)

Comment: I see. Any idea knowing  this new information then?

Comment: You could probably make some changes the same way as you would for a theme using the standard hooks, e.g. `wp_title` for the title etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a child theme, install it [see docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

In the child theme create a header.php file.
Modify it to your needs, wordpress first checks if the child theme has a template, if it has it uses it instead of the parent theme template.

You can start your modification by copying the contents of parent theme' header.php file, then change what you need.

Comment: I want to reuse the current theme, though. I am not creating a template. I am creating a plugin that adds a custom page and I want to reuse the installed theme + do some custom addition in the header for my custom page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using one of the hooks to remove the title and then echo all the content I want to add into the `<head>` tag.

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag', 1);
add_action( 'wp_head', 'render_my_additional_head_content', 1);
```